# Expansion of wave function and energy in terms of small parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In time-independent perturbation theory, the Hamiltonian is perturbed with a perturbation of the form $\lambda V$, and the eigen-energies and wave-functions of the unperturbed Hamiltonian are expressed as series in powers of $\lambda$:

$$E =E^{(0)} + \lambda E^{(1)} + \lambda^2 E^{(2)} +...,$$
$$\rvert n \rangle = \rvert n \rangle^{(0)} + \lambda \rvert n \rangle^{(1)} + \lambda^2 \rvert n \rangle^{(2)} +...$$

But why is the same parameter $\lambda$ used both in the expression $\lambda V$, and in the expansion? It makes sense that in the limit $\lambda \to 0$, $E \to E^{(0)}$ and $\rvert n \rangle \to \rvert n \rangle^{(0)}$. But is there a formal way to see why the expansion works generally? I feel like it is some sort of a Taylor expansion.

I am looking for a more formal reasoning as to why this expansion in powers of $\lambda$ would be appropriate in this correction. Maybe there's a way to derive it. Even the Taylor series for a function has a formal derivation; I am looking for a similar argument as to why the eigenkets and eigenvalues depend on $\lambda$ in a power series expansion, and not some other way.

Answer (score 1):

The perturbation is usually written in the form $\lambda V$ to make its dependence on a small parameter explicit. Clearly, the eigenstates and eigenvalues of your hamiltonian must depend on $\lambda$ as well and therefore one may hope that it can be expanded around $\lambda=0$ (yes, you can think of it as a Taylor expansion). The existence of such an expansion requires that the perturbed solutions are smoothly connected to the unperturbed solutions, which is an assumption made here. Perturbation theory may fail, e.g. if a phase transition occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for a more formal reasoning as to why the expansion would be appropriate in this correction. Maybe there's a way to derive it. Even the Taylor series for a function has a formal derivation; I am looking for a similar argument as to why the eigenkets and eigenvalues depend on $\lambda$ in a power series expansion, and not some other way.